# TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer rails 5.1.3

Tags: heroku, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.1

My rails project runs locally but get error when deployed to heroku. 
You can see the logs below. 
(Rails 5.1.3, ruby 2.5.0dev)

Please help :)

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline  
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile  
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.  
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install  
remote:        rake aborted!  
remote:        TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer  
remote: /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/source_map_utils.rb:47:in `[]'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/source_map_utils.rb:47:in `format_source_map'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:33:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'  
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'  
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:144:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:166:in `dfs'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:144:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:32:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:31:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:144:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/base.rb:69:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/base.rb:76:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0.beta5/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `block in synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `synchronize'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/promise.rb:531:in `block in realize'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
remote:        /tmp/build_97bbbdb340e28756f50c5e83afe21dc9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
```